# Running jar on hadoop server as a service

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-10.04

i made one jar

which analyzes system logs .. for running this jar on HADOOP server i can do it using command line like "bin/hadoop jar log.jar"

but my problem is i want to make this jar executable in background as a service on Ubuntu master machine.

can any one help me how can i make HADOOP jar as a service so it can run like a background service on Ubuntu Machine .. runs after every 1hrs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options, here's two:

- Configure a [crontab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job to run your job every hour, something like (you'll need to fully qualify the path to hadoop and the jar itself):

> ```
>   0 * * * *   /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar /path/to/jar/log.jar
> ```

- Run an [OOZIE](http://oozie.apache.org) server and configure a coordinator to submit the job on an hourly basis. More effort that the above suggestion but worth a look.

Comment: +1 for the Oozie solution over the cron job, specially if your plan  to add more hadoop jobs that would have dependencies between each other.